# How to control auto increment id?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have an entity with a strategy to auto generate an id based on an integer column in MySQL. Things work, but while testing exceptions and related rollbacks, I noticed that MySQL does not reset last incremented value.

So a successful save produces entity id 1
An attempted save gets entity id 2 but is rolled back.
Then a successful save of a new entity gets entity id 3.

Consequently, in the table we have two records. One with id 1 and the other with id 3.

Are there any ways to control this? Basically, in the scenario I have just described, I would like to see two entities: one with id set to 1 and the other with id set to 2.

Comment: Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Usually one doesn't want what you want. Suppose you would want to log  some critical information about the entity that got rolled back (part of a complicated transaction). The fact that there will be a unique log entry could be of crucial importance later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-increment numbers have to be unique, but they don't have to be consecutive. They are monotonically increasing only as a coincidence of their implementation.

You can always insert a specific value and bypass the auto-increment mechanism. But you'd have to know what value is the "next" value. To avoid race conditions, you'd have to lock the table, query the MAX(id)+1 and then insert that value.

And that's exactly what MySQL would have to do, too, if it were to do this automatically.

The way auto-increment works now allows maximum concurrency without race conditions. So it is by design that it "loses" some values from time to time, when you rollback an INSERT, or else if you subsequently DELETE a value.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change that. That is how it is supposed to be.

An auto-increment id has to be unique. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle it using your own auto increment logic.
Have a Max+1 idgenerator or have a table that maintains PK auto generated IDs of such tables.
A table like this

**LastKey    TableName**
1          TableX
5          TableY

Everytime, you will have to query from this table to get the incremented id.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I think this would only work for a single connection. As soon as we have two concurrent transactions asking for the next id, we'd run into problems.